# Run Server in Virtual Box with Client in Host OS - How to enable connection

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

[In network engineering stackexchange I was told to post this here, sorry if I'm offtopic again].

The problem I face is the following: I got a license file for a program and have to set up a license server to use it. Since this server software requires a linux OS, I set up a virtual machine in Virtual Box with linux centos 7. The server is up and running as far as I can tell. The problem is now, that my client is not able to establish a connection. The program is Xilinx Vivado, the software running on the virtual server is called flexlm. In the Vivado license manager (client) I'm supposed to provide port number and IP adress in the format

2100@IP-adress

However, the client does not find anything. I was told that I have to manage the network settings in Virtual Box, but so far, nobody could tell me exactly what to do. I tried with "NAT" mode and activated a port forwarding from host to client OS (mapping 2100 on 2100). I also tried "Bridge Adapter" but this didn't help either. Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue? Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with networking stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to do some network debugging. Doing a port-forward from host to the VBox VM sounds like a good start. Can you reach the license server from the VBox host machine on localhost:2100 ? Go through each step in how the packets are supposed to go from the client to the server and see where things stop working.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can check whether the server is available from the host machine? I don't really know how I can verify this. What I tried so far (because a colleague told me to do so):
- There is a tool called lmutil which I can execute on the guest machine. Executing this gave me an output on the centos console which essentially told me that the server is up and running. What exactly it tests I don't know unfortunately.
- I started an ssh server on the VM and accessed it via putty from my normal (windows) OS. This was working fine, I did that to verify that port forwarding was working.